# how to store only these file types

Tags: php

this is my code for allowed these file types to store data but it only stored .pdf file how can i store another files like .ppt, .docx and txt ?

```
$validate_file_extension =  $files = $_FILES["content"]['type'] =="application/pdf" ||
    $files = $_FILES["content"]['type'] =="application/doc" ||
    $files = $_FILES["content"]['type'] =="application/msword" ||
    $files = $_FILES["content"]['type'] =="application/txt" ||
    $files = $_FILES["content"]['type'] =="application/ppt" ;

    if($validate_file_extension)
```

Comment: When you upload, do you get `application/octet-stream`?

Comment: nope i use basic post method to retrieve data from  html form to my databse then i get file extension which i mentioned above i want to store only doc ,pdf ,ppt or text files.

Comment: _“nope i use basic post method […]”_ - that is not an answer to the question you were asked. Go make a debug output of `$_FILES["content"]['type']`, and then see what that _actually_ contains when you upload one of your “not working” file types.

Comment: when i want to upload .docx file it give this  output {application/octet-stream }  from $_FILES["content"]['type'] this code

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path, but I suggest putting the allowed types in an array to clean up your code.

```
ValidateFileExtension($_FILES['content']);

function ValidateFileExtension($file) {
    
    // array of allowed MIME types
    $allowedFileExtensions = 
        ["application/doc", 
         "application/msword", 
         "application/txt", 
         "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"
        ];
    
    // get the MIME type of the file
    $fileMimeType = $file['type'];
    
    // return TRUE if file type is in array or FALSE if it is not
    return in_array($fileMimeType, $allowedFileExtensions)
    
}
```

Here's a list of MIME types: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

In there you can find the MIME type associated with the extension you want to add to the list of allowed types

Answer (score 0):

```
//fetch the mime type of the file
$file_type = $_FILES['content']['type'];

// array of allowed MIME types
$allowedFileTypes = 
    ["application/doc", 
     "application/msword", 
     "application/txt", 
     "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"
    ];

if(!in_array($file_type, $allowedFileTypes)) {
  $error_message = 'Only doc, msword and txt files are allowed';
}
```